# How to upload a file using httpwebrequest c#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want to upload a file using a `restwebservice`. I am able to do it using `webclient`, but I want to do it using `httpwebrequest`. As, I suspect `webclient` is very slow. So, how to post a file to a server using `httpwebrequest webservice`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: you can refer this link to solve you questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Comment: Why do you suspect "webclient is very slow"? It's in fact, just a wrapper around HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I have two types of webservices to upload file.In one, I convert the meta data alongwith the file data to base64 string and post it to the server.In the other, I send the meta data as headers and send the file using uploadfileasync.The first(using webrequest) webservice is twice as fast as second for uploading 2 MB file.The speed is almost same for 200 KB file.